# Is there roslaunch python package in ros2?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. Sorry for all mistakes, English is not my native language. In my ROS1 project I have a python script that can launch specific list of launch files depending on clicked button in rqt. This script have following lines of code:

```
import roslaunch
...
class RosService(roslaunch.pmon.ProcessListener):
...
    self.uuid = roslaunch.rlutil.get_or_generate_uuid(None, False)
...
    self.launch_path = roslaunch.rlutil.resolve_launch_arguments(args)[0]
...
        self.parent = roslaunch.parent.ROSLaunchParent(self.uuid, [(self.launch_path,self.launch_args)], 
            process_listeners = [self],
            force_screen = self.force_screen, 
            force_log = self.force_log)
```

Is there a way to use something similar in ROS2? I know that there are ros2launch package, but, maybe I miss something, as far as I understand this package is very much different from roslaunch from ROS1. Appreciate any help. If there is an example of implementation similar functionality in any other project, I  would be very grateful for chance to look on it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409181/is-there-roslaunch-python-package-in-ros2?/) by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2022-11-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps QML could suit you:

- https://discourse.ros.org/t/create-stunning-uis-for-ros2-using-the-newly-released-qml-ros2-plugin/25906
- https://github.com/StefanFabian/qml_ros2_plugin

> Connects QML and ROS2 enabling the simple creation of great looking Graphical User Interfaces for robotics applications.

I would also like to see other answers with pure RViz and ROS2 launch files

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2022-11-09**:
Thank you for your help. As far as I understand this is not what I looking for. I already have rqt interface to work with my robot, the problem is I don't have necessary package which allows me to launch specific list of launch files for different requirements. Still, I appreciate that you are trying to help.